# How to compile/link static library with DMD

Tags: linker, d, dmd

Whenever I build a static library using DMD, I'm able to link it to my application and it compiles fine but anytime in the application the library is called I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

For building the library I do

```
# $(FILE) for each file in "find source -name "*.d"
# $(OBJ) is $(FILE) with the extension ".o"
# $(IMP) is $(FILE) with the extension ".di"
dmd -O -d -m64 -L-ldl -m64 -Isource -c $(FILE) -ofbuild/$(OBJ)

ar rcs ./lib/libvibe.d-dmd.a build/*
ranlib ./lib/libvibe.d-dmd.a

dmd -O -d -m64 -L-ldl -m64 -Isource -c -o- $(FILE) -Hfimport/$(IMP)
```

and for building the application

```
SRC = $(shell find src -name "*.d")
dmd -debug -odbuild -I../../vibe.d/source -L-L../../vibe.d/lib -L-lvibe.d-dmd $(SRC) -ofbin/test
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Update

Compiling vibe.d as libvibe.d-dmd.a

```
dmd -g -lib -oflib/libvibe.d-dmd.a $(SOURCES) -L-levent_pthreads -L-levent -L-lssl -L-lcrypto
```

Example code:

```
import vibe.core.file;
void main()
{
  openFile("test.d", FileMode.Read);
}
```

Compiling the example

```
dmd -g test.d vibe.d/lib/libvibe.d-dmd.a -Ivibe.d/source
```

And some gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004554f5 in vibe.core.file.openFile() (mode=<incomplete type>, path=...) at source/vibe/core/file.d:29
29      return getEventDriver().openFile(path, mode);
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004554f5 in vibe.core.file.openFile() (mode=<incomplete type>, path=...) at source/vibe/core/file.d:29
#1  0x000000000044f7d2 in vibe.core.file.openFile() (mode=<incomplete type>, path=...) at source/vibe/inet/path.d:24
#2  0x000000000044f539 in D main () at test.d:5
#3  0x000000000046b9e4 in rt.dmain2.main() ()
#4  0x000000000046b35e in rt.dmain2.main() ()
#5  0x000000000046ba2b in rt.dmain2.main() ()
#6  0x000000000046b35e in rt.dmain2.main() ()
#7  0x000000000046b2e9 in main ()
(gdb) fram 2
#2  0x000000000044f539 in D main () at test.d:5
5     openFile("test.d", FileMode.Read);
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x000000000044f7d2 in vibe.core.file.openFile() (mode=<incomplete type>, path=...) at source/vibe/inet/path.d:24
24  struct Path {
(gdb) print mode
$1 = <incomplete type>
```

Comment: Well, it has probably nothing to do with linking or compiling. A segmentation fault indicates that your program has problem with memory access. Wikipedia link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault. You should also remove the gcc tag, since your question is not related to it.

Comment: @undu a wrongly linked application will segfault (when dereferrencing the function pointer)

Comment: @undu directly from dlang.org in DMD's linking Section: "The actual linking is done by running gcc."

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the `dmd -lib -oflibmylib.a file1.d ...`?

The best thing you can do is to run GDB, and see why your application segfaults. If you see that the reason for segfault is dereferencing a function pointer from your library then it is most likely you are right and something went wrong with linking.

If you are not familiar with GDB, here is an easy article how to do it: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html .

There is also a nice article on [Wiki4D](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?D__Tutorial/CompilingLinkingD) about this topic.

Here is a whole session how to compile a library `libdstlib.a` out of two files `dstlib/foo.d` and `dstdlib/bar.d`:

```
dejan@homeserver:~/work/dstlib> ls -R
.:
driver.d  dstlib

./dstlib:
bar.d  foo.d
dejan@homeserver:~/work/dstlib> dmd -lib -oflibdstlib.a dstlib/*.d
dejan@homeserver:~/work/dstlib> dmd driver.d libdstlib.a
dejan@homeserver:~/work/dstlib> ./driver
w: 80, h: 40
dejan@homeserver:~/work/dstlib> cat driver.d dstlib/foo.d dstlib/bar.d
module driver;
import std.stdio;
import dstlib.bar;

void main()
{
    auto rect = getRectangle();
    rect.display();
}    
module dstlib.foo;
import std.stdio : writefln;
struct Rectangle
{
    int width, height;
    void display()
    {
        writefln("w: %s, h: %s", width, height);
    }
}    
module dstlib.bar;
import dstlib.foo;

Rectangle getRectangle()
{
    return Rectangle(80, 40);
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing with different methods from the Wiki4D link and added gdb output in original question. Thanks for the help.